# IE end of life implications for Cognos Query Studio

Tags: internet-explorer, cognos

IE is going to retire next year. This will affect legacy tools, our business users rely on Query Studio to perform their job. What are your plans for your users once IE sunsets.

I understand the IE will still be functional but will not be maintained and might be a security liability for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are numerous good reasons to move to a different technology than Query Studio, IBM officially supports Query Studio on Firefox ESR 78 even on the latest Cognos 11.2.1.  This may relieve any immediate pressure you are facing to find an alternative to the entire system.  Obviously, your ability to take advantage of this depends on the difficulty in training your business users that they must use another browser for Query Studio.  Chrome and Chromium-based Edge are not supported for Query Studio by IBM at this time.

[image: Firefox ESR support for Query Studio]

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-cognos-analytics-premises-112x-supported-software-environments